# C# Database issue

Tags: c#, sql, database, forms

Could somebody tell me why this isn't adding the values to the database. The form runs fine and doesn't return any errors.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

        connection.ConnectionString = (@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\John\Documents\Setup.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", textBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passWord", textBox2.Text);
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Setup (userName, password) VALUES(@userName, @passWord)";



        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle exception
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }


    }
```

FYI: I'm a "newbie" My database is called Setup. I've manually added a table called myTable with 2 columns of userName and another one called password both set at nchar(50)

Comment: Change `insert into Setup` to `insert into myTable`

Comment: Tip - it's better (and shorter) to use `using() {}` for example - `using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        // Do work here; connection closed on following line.
    }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the `Table`, not the database (which gets used in the connection string).  Added the schema prefix to the table name:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.myTable (userName, password) VALUES (@userName, @passWord)";
```

And add:

```
command.Connection = connection;
```

to associate your `Command` object with the connection object.

Comment: This still doesn't work unfortunately. Just so i'm thinking correctly, once i've ran the form and closed it when I click 'show table data' the newly added values should be there.

Comment: @user1353517 The "posted" code should work.  Make sure your button click event is wired up.  When you click on `button1`, does it run the code?

Comment: @user1353517 Missed that.  You need to associate the command object with the connection.  Updated answer.

Comment: thanks, I've added it but now I get the erro 'Invalid object name 'myTable'.' on line 'int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();'

Comment: @user1353517 Then you don't have a table called `myTable` in your database.  Double check the database you are referencing in the connection string.

Comment: I 100% do have a table called myTable. Been at this all day and really can't figure it out

Comment: @user1353517 Try changing it to `dbo.myTable` the way Siva suggested.

Comment: @Siva Pulling at straws without the ability to sit at the OP's computer.

Comment: @user1353517 Add this line after your executed query: `MessageBox.Show("Inserted: " + rowsAffected.ToString());` What does it report?

Comment: It now just gives me the error 'Invalid object name 'myTable'' Maybe it's something to do with the way I set the table up. Was there any sort of data adapter settings I was meant to change? All I did was 'Add new table' typed in userName and set it to nchar(50) and set password to nchar(50)

Comment: @user1353517 My best guess here is that the database you are looking at and the one in the code are two different things.

Comment: It can't be. Here's exactly what I did. Created a new project, went to Data - Add new data source - then followed the steps, tested the connection and it was fine and I copied the connection string from that.

Comment: @user1353517 Oh, it can be.  I'm guessing you said "yes" when you created the database and it asked you if you wanted the database to be a part of the project.  That "moves" the database.  Do this: From your [Database Explorer] window, right-click on "setup.mdf" and selected "Properties".  Look at the "Connection" property.  I bet it's different than the one in your code.  Blame Microsoft.

Comment: HOLY CRAP I DID IT :D :D for some reason it wasn't working from the documents folder so I just moved it inside the project folder and boom YES. Thanks for all your help :D !!!

Answer (score 1):

> The form runs fine and doesn't return any errors.

That's probably because you're swallowing them. Get rid of (or log) your `catch (Exception ex)`.

In general, the .NET BCL is well-designed - if a method isn't going to work, you will get an exception.

> [Now] I have the error 'ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.'

Right. You need to pass the `SqlConnection` to the `SqlCommand`:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
```

Comment: Okay, now I have the error 'ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.' on line int 'rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();' Any Idea?

Comment: Added it an I get the error 'the best overloaded method match for 'system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.sqlcommand(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @user1353517 - Oops. Can't pass the connection to ctor. Set the SqlCommand.Connection property instead

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look something like this:

- Set the connection object.
- Specify the table name as @LarsTech has mentioned.
- It is a best practice to use two part notation when specifying table names like `[Schema name].[Table Name]`. So, you have to specify your table name like `dbo.MyTable`

*Code snippet*:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = (@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\John\Documents\Setup.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;");

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable  (userName, password) VALUES (@userName, @passWord)";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", textBox1.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passWord", textBox2.Text);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //handle exception
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't add the values to the database :(